Unable to make xpath work for an HTML block of code
I have this html block:
<td><a href="#" class="">   <i class="far fa-times mr-1"></i>Cancel</a></td>

I wrote the following xpath to find this Cancel anchor, but this is not working. What am I doing wrong?
//a[contains(text(), 'Cancel')]

The following xpath works but i need to learn what am i doing wrong in the above one:
//i[@class='far fa-times mr-1']/..


//a[contains(text(), 'Cancel')]

Issue: The reason above XPath expression is not working is because, above XPath looks for an anchor (<a>) element containing the text Cancel. However, the <a> element in your HTML snippet doesn't directly contain the text Cancel. Instead, it contains an <i> element and then the text Cancel.
Solution: Change the XPath expression as below:
//a[contains(., 'Cancel')]

XPath explanation: The . represents the current node, so contains(., 'Cancel') checks for the presence of "Cancel" text within the <a> element and all of its descendants.

This is working. Will read details on this. Thank you @Shawn

The explanation is not correct.
The probleem is not that the Cancel-text is inside i. (it is not inside).
The problem is that the first argument of contains should be a single string.
And since a has 2 text-nodes, it fails. The first text-node is the white-space only node, the second is the one with Cancel  inside.

Which part of explanation is not correct? I don't think I have mentioned anywhere in the answer that Cancel text is inside the <i> node.

You say: However, the <a> element in your HTML snippet doesn't directly contain the text Cancel. But is DOES contain it directly. It is 2e direct text()-node.

The problem is that the first argument of contains should be a single string. And since a has 2 text()-nodes, it fails. The 1e text()-node is the white-space only text-node, the 2e text()-node is the one with Cancel  inside.
<a href="#"><!--1e-->   <i class="far fa-times mr-1"></i>><!--2e-->Cancel</a>

I see two alternatives:

//a[contains(., 'Cancel')]
The . will combine all descendent text-nodes into one string.

//a[contains(text()[normalize-space()], 'Cancel')] . The [normalize-space()]-predicate will select only those text-nodes that have besides white-space actual character-data. Ans since that is only one, it will succeed.



Suggestion... put the beautified/formatted HTML in your answer and indicate clearly where the first text node is. I think it will make your explanation clearer.
